# Show different div according to which link i click

Tags: javascript, css

On my html page I have made four different links in the top. Under that I have four div-elements. On page load i want them all to be hidden.

Now my problem. I want the divs to get visible with a transition ease slide down effect when I click on the links. So if i click on "Show Blue" the div with id="blue" slides down and gets visible. If i then click on another link e.g. "Show green" the visible div slides up and the selected is now sliding down and gets visible and so on.

I have tried with some js onClick, but i can't get working right
Hope that some of you can help me.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

.content_holder {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #bfdc37;
  height: 100px;
}

a {
  margin: 20px;
}

.color {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #bfdc37;
  height: 100px;
  display: none;

}
```

```html
    <div class="content_holder">
        <div class="box" id="box1">
            <a href="#">Show Blue</a>
        </div>

        <div class="box" id="box2">
            <a href="#">Show Red</a>
        </div>

        <div class="box" id="box3">
            <a href="#">Show Yellow</a>
        </div>

        <div class="box" id="box4">
            <a href="#">Show Green</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="color" id="blue">
        This box says blue
    </div>

    <div class="color" id="red">
        This box says red
    </div>

    <div class="color" id="yellow">
        This box says yellow
    </div>

    <div class="color" id="green">
        This box says green
    </div>
```

Comment: As your question is tagged javascript where is it?

Comment: I have not included it because it only get it work with one link and one div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy to do with jQuery. You can code your animated opening and closing.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".box").click(function(){
                $(".color").css("display", "none");
                var data = $(this).attr("data");
                $('.color[id='+data+']').css("display", "inline");
            });
        });
    </script>
```

I've just added `data` attribute to divs.

```
        <div class="box" id="box1" data="blue">
            <a href="#">Show Blue</a>
        </div>

        <div class="box" id="box2" data="red">
            <a href="#">Show Red</a>
        </div>

        <div class="box" id="box3" data="yellow">
            <a href="#">Show Yellow</a>
        </div>

        <div class="box" id="box4" data="green">
            <a href="#">Show Green</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="color" id="blue">
        This box says blue
    </div>

    <div class="color" id="red">
        This box says red
    </div>

    <div class="color" id="yellow">
        This box says yellow
    </div>

    <div class="color" id="green">
        This box says green
    </div>
```